# DynamoDB Staging/Production/Development versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

It seems that there is no way to create a database in Amazon DynamoDB with its own name, you can only create tables.

But we would like to separate databases for Staging/Development/Production environments.

How can this be resolved? By creating a new AWS account?

Comment: Ok found the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877136/managing-dev-staging-production-on-dynamodb?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a separate DynamoDB account.  It's good for a whole number of reasons:

- Assurance that test data isn't leaking into production (don't give prod credentials to test hosts)
- Ability to break out spending on test infrastructure from production
- Inability to break prod functionality with test bugs
- Guarantee that developers without priviledge can't see secure production data (if necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Besides creating a new AWS account you can use prefixes for Dynamo tables. For example, `production-users`, `test-users`, etc.

However, for development purposes I'd recommend to use DynamoDB Local with [`jcabi-dynamodb-maven-plugin`](http://dynamodb.jcabi.com/index.html). The plugin starts a local version of DynamoDB before your integration tests and shuts it down right after. Much more convenient and stable than relying on a "test" table in DynamoDB.