# dynamodb - splitting development and production by region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using dynamodb, and I want to separate my development environment from production. I've seen two ways of doing this: one by prefixing the tables, e.g MyTable_Dev vs. MyTable_Prod, and the other by opening separate account and using consolidated billing. But I wanted to hear your opinion about a third way: separating environments by region, say production in western Europe vs. development in central Europe. Code-wise, it would be very easy for me to do. But do you think it is a good solution? does it scale?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing dev/staging/production on DynamoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877136/managing-dev-staging-production-on-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

To separate dev vs. production environments, given a choice of these options:

1. Prefix table names
2. Use separate regions
3. Use separate AWS accounts

Use option 3.

Prefixing table names is just asking for trouble. Your code would have to be "environment-aware" to know to talk to `Table_dev` or `Table_prod`. Don't do this.

Using separate regions would work, but you could accidentally do something in the wrong region.

The best solution is to use separated AWS accounts for dev and prod. This way, you can duplicate an environment:

1. with the same table names
2. with the same region

with the added bonus of extra security allowing people to work in the dev environments but not the prod environments. You would give your developers access to the dev environment knowing they cannot break the prod environment.

Comment: But you login to an account with your email address. Is it possible to use the same email for production and development environments?

Comment: You'll need a 2nd email address to create a 2nd AWS account. It's easy to do and your users won't hate you because your app goes down when a developer nuked a production table by accident.

Comment: Also, ensure you're using IAM users to sign-in rather than using the root account.

Comment: I would add that #3 also has some negatives, such as overhead of managing multiple IAM accounts and permissions, setting up [consolidated billing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html), and the general overhead of managing multiple accounts. Unfortunately AWS billing and tags aren't supported for [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/allocation-how.html). The feature was [suggested](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=179112) about a year ago, but no news yet.

Comment: I am more in favor of the prefixes/conventions, but separate accounts is another option that has been [suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877136/managing-dev-staging-production-on-dynamodb), and was the recommended way for a while.